use ring-bell-function along with visible-bell
Is it possible to use ring-bell-function along with visible-bell?
I would like to have a config to both play the bell sound and also flash the mode-line. Below are 2 config's I tried without success - both of them just play sound without visible indicator.
I found in the Emacs documentation that

If ring-bell-function is non-nil, it takes precedence over the visible-bell variable.

does this mean only one of these 2 can be used at a time?

Config1: (reference)
(setq visible-bell nil
      ring-bell-function 'flash-mode-line)

(defun flash-mode-line ()
  (play-sound-file ""C:/Windows/Media/Windows Ding.wav"")
  (invert-face 'mode-line)
  (run-with-timer 0.1 nil #'invert-face 'mode-line))

Config2: (reference)
(setq visible-bell nil
      ring-bell-function 'flash-mode-line)
(defun flash-mode-line ()
  (play-sound-file ""C:/Windows/Media/Windows Ding.wav"")
   (let ((orig-fg (face-foreground 'mode-line)))
          (set-face-foreground 'mode-line "#F2804F")
          (run-with-idle-timer 0.1 nil
                               (lambda (fg) (set-face-foreground 'mode-line fg))
                               orig-fg)))


found this related question in stackoverflow, not sure how to use this in a config

additonally you can use the config in this answer to disable ring-bell for chosen actions

(setopt ring-bell-function (lambda ()
                             (ding)
                             ;; Your code here:
                             ...))


ding is a built-in function in ‘src/dispnew.c’.

Beep, or flash the screen.


For future reference, I updated the config with @shynur's response and got it to work with below code:
(defun flash-mode-line ()
  (ding)
  (let ((orig-bg (face-background 'mode-line)))
    (set-face-background 'mode-line "#F2804F")
    (run-with-idle-timer 0.1 nil
                         (lambda (bg) (set-face-background 'mode-line bg))
                         orig-bg)))
 (setq visible-bell nil
      ring-bell-function #'flash-mode-line
      )

